# clean dataframe where variable position is inconsistent across columns, for ex. stock index where members are added or deleted overtime

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

consider below dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['03/06/19','03/06/19','03/07/19','03/07/19','03/08/19','03/08/19'], 'Column_1': ['a_id',0.1,'a_id',0.1,'b_id',0.15],\
         'Column_2':['b_id',0.15,'b_id',0.15,'c_id',0.2]})

print(df)

    date    Column_1    Column_2
0   03/06/19    a_id    b_id
1   03/06/19    0.1     0.15
2   03/07/19    a_id    b_id
3   03/07/19    0.1     0.15
4   03/08/19    b_id    c_id
5   03/08/19    0.15    0.2
```

The challenge with this externally sourced data is that: the positioning of the elements is not consistent. for example 'b_id' and 'c_id' above are mixed into a single column.

I wish to clean this format, so that i can get the output in below format

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'date':['03/06/19','03/07/19','03/08/19'], 'a_id':[0.1,0.1,np.nan],'b_id':[0.15,0.15,0.15],'c_id':[0.2,np.nan,np.nan]})

print(out)
     date      a_id  b_id   c_id
0   03/06/19    0.1  0.15   0.2
1   03/07/19    0.1  0.15   NaN
2   03/08/19    NaN  0.15   NaN
```

I have managed to find a solution, but it is highly manual and require me to run loops which is very expensive on a large dataset.

Here is my (very unpythonic) solution:

```
temp = df.T

temp2 = temp.iloc[:,0:2]

temp2 = temp2.set_index(temp2.iloc[:,0], drop=True)

temp3 = temp.iloc[:,2:4]

temp3 = temp3.set_index(temp3.iloc[:,0], drop=True)

temp2 = pd.merge(left=temp2, right=temp3, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

**# repeat process in a loop!**
temp3 = temp.iloc[:,4:6]

temp3 = temp3.set_index(temp3.iloc[:,0], drop=True)

temp2 = pd.merge(left=temp2, right=temp3, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer')

**# clean the final database!**
out = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_numeric(np.hstack(temp2.values), errors='coerce')\
         .reshape(temp2.shape), columns=temp2.columns, index=temp2.index).dropna(how='all', axis=1)


print(out.T)

            a_id    b_id    c_id
 date           
 03/06/19   0.1     0.15    NaN
 03/07/19   0.1     0.15    NaN
 03/08/19   NaN     0.15    0.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from your example:

```
x = df.to_numpy()
columns=['date', 'a_id', 'b_id', 'c_id']
pd.DataFrame([{'date': a[0], a[1] : b[1], a[2] : b[2]}for a, b in zip(x[0::2], x[1::2])], columns=columns)
```

gives:

```
    date    a_id    b_id    c_id
0   03/06/19    0.1 0.15    NaN
1   03/07/19    0.1 0.15    NaN
2   03/08/19    NaN 0.15    0.2
```

Comment: beautiful solution. I will just figure out how this would work on a much larger dataframe (the above example was just a representative sample) before I accept this answer.